# Email validation in PHP won't work properly

Tags: php, mysql

I added validation on email input, but it is not working, why?

the error is that when I give input as `example@yah.oo.com`; not showing any error messages, why?

**my code is**

```
else if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo "email is not valid";
    return false;

}
```

I also used `preg_match` function but the same problem occurs,
can any one tell me why it is not showing any validation message.
As of my knowledge, that an email address only contains one dot(.) is it

Comment: *Why?* -- it's valid [email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address).

Comment: *Is it right?* -> No. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples).

Comment: Better - see [RFC2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation is correct - your understanding is wrong. An email address of `joe.soap@example.co.uk` (two dots) is valid, as is `joe.soap@email.example.co.uk` (three dots), etc.

The only reliable way to validate an email address is to send a message to it.

Comment: oh.. you mean we can put more then one dot(.) after the @ and before the @?

Comment: Absolutely. `joe.soap.snr@private.email.example.com.au` is also valid.

Comment: This is one of the biggest questions in computer programmings. Email validation is a HUGE area of computer science and you will see blogs dedicated to possible emails address that will break email validation.  First rule of email validation is that it probably has an @ in it.

Comment: @JohnBallinger Computer _science_? Have you read RFC2822? `Black arts` is nearer the mark!

Answer (score 0):

You can make one yourself like the one below;

```
function checkEmail($email){
        return eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email);
    }
```